# How can I use makefile to run typeset document with bibliorgaphy?

Tags: biblatex, biber, makefile, filecontents

Recently I was introduced to typeset LaTeX documents with `makefile`, and I liked that idea. However, when come to the case where I have bibliography, things becomes complicated. First of all, I generate bibliography file generated by package `filecontents`. Here is my MWE

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks = false, pdfborderstyle ={/S/D}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none, maxnames = 3, minnames = 2, backref = true, backrefstyle = three, arxiv = abs, doi = true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biber.bib}
@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross section in $p p$ collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 2.76 \mathrm{TeV}$ and comparison to the inclusive jet cross section at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using the ATLAS detector},
journal = {The European Physical Journal C},
year = {2013},
month = {August},
volume = {73},
number = {2509},
doi = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-013-2509-4},
}

@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
month = {February},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
volume = {02},
number = {153},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153},
addendum = {\textbf{Erratum}: \cite{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}},
}

@article
{
a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
title = {Erratum: Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt{s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
year = {2015},
month = {September},
volume = {09},
number = {141},
doi = {10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biber.bib}

\begin{document}

I will cite \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}, which has the erratum, first, then \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet}.

\newpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It all works fine when I use an editor (texshop) to typeset, however, when it comes to the `makefile`

```
main=test
run:
    pdflatex $(main)
    bibtex $(main).aux
    pdflatex $(main)
    rm -f $(main).aux
    rm -f $(main).bbl
    rm -f $(main).bcf
    rm -f $(main).log
    rm -f $(main).out
    rm -f $(main).run.xml
    rm -f $(main).synctex.gz
    rm -f $(main).toc
    rm -f *.bib
```

it starts to give me various error message

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file note.aux
```

I am not sure how to make this work, could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you need to run biber and not bibtex. Also, you need at least two calls to pdflatex after the bibliography is generated.

Comment: And please give your database another name and stop using filecontents to manage it.

Comment: Try `latexmk -pdf` instead of `pdflatex`, `bibtex` (or `biber`) and `pdflatex`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit So nice! It worked! One single call of `latexmk -pdf` did the job! Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes_B I use `filecontents` to manage because I really like the idea of being able to edit bibliography and text in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `latexmk` script is very useful in a `makefile` since it detects and automates the sequence of all the necessary commands: in your case, it will be able to call `pdflatex` then `biber` (and not `bibtex`) then again at least twice `pdflatex`...

```
latexmk -pdf document.tex
```

To clean up all intermediate files, use the `-c` option:

```
latexmk -c -pdf document.tex
```

Notice this only does the clean up, so if you would like to typeset and then clean up, you would do:

```
latexmk -pdf document.tex
latexmk -c -pdf document.tex
```